# How to get an exact pixel-perfect gap between flex elements with justify-content center?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I thought that saying `gap: 24px` would mean 24px gap, even if I used `justify-content: center` and `flex-wrap: wrap`. But it's turning out to not be true, as I resize the screen it grows and shrinks, roughly around 24px but slightly larger and smaller in some cases :/.

```
$0.offsetLeft
539
$0.previousElementSibling.offsetLeft + $0.previousElementSibling.offsetWidth
514

539 - 514 = 25 (for example, one measurement)
```

[image]

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 24px;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 140px;
  background: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try and resizing the screen rendering that demo, the gap gets slightly (barely noticeably) larger and smaller.

How do you prevent this? How can you make it so the gap is hardcoded to 24px?

Comment: What is your devices CSS to screen pixel ratio?